# How to programmatically obtain relative power consumption?

Tags: c++, windows, macos

Recently I need to monitor the battery consumption of some process.

The method I already know is to get it through top:

```
top -stats pid,command,cpu,idlew,power -o power -d
```

In addition, it can also be obtained in the Activity Monitor of macOS, but I do not know whether there is an operating system interface, so that I can directly obtain a relative value of the power consumption of a process.

I tried to use [proc_pid_rusage](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/libsyscall/wrappers/libproc/libproc.h.auto.html). The returned parameters are `ri_billed_energy` and `ri_serviced_energy`, but they are always 0. I want to know if there are other interfaces or methods that allow me to get this value.